# Seg fault using strtok to parse stdin to an array

Tags: c, stdin, strtok

I'm getting a seg fault every time the code reaches the first strtok

```
token = strtok(commandLine," ");
```

I'm just trying to parse stdin and store it, using a space as a delimiter. A lot of problems I saw were people using strtok on a string literal, which I assume also applies to my case as well, but how do I work around that?
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //Used for parsing
    char commandLine[255];
    char* tokens[10];
    char* token;
    int counter;
    int i;

    printf("gets to pt 1\n");
    //Parsing
    while( fgets(commandLine, 255, stdin) ){
        printf("\n%s\n", commandLine);
        token = strtok(commandLine," ");
        printf("gets here");
        counter = 0;
        for(counter = 0; token != NULL; counter++){
            strcpy(tokens[counter], token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }   
    }
    printf("gets to point2");
    for(i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++){
        printf("%s ", tokens[i]);
    }
```

EDIT:

Here is the working code.

As User93353 pointed out, I had to allocate memory for my tokens so I changed

```
char* tokens[10]
```

to

```
char tokens[10][100]
```

and my for loop wasn't ending correctly, had to change

```
tokens[i] != NULL
```

to

```
i<counter
```

-

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //Used for parsing
    char commandLine[255];
    char tokens[10][100];
    char* token;
    int counter;
    int i;

    printf("gets to pt 1\n");
    //Parsing
    while( fgets(commandLine, 255, stdin) ){
        printf("\n%s\n", commandLine);
        token = strtok(commandLine," ");
        printf("gets here");
        for(counter = 0; token != NULL; counter++){
            strcpy(tokens[counter], token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        printf("gets to printing");
        for(i = 0; i<counter; i++){
            printf("%s", tokens[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `strcpy(tokens[counter], token);` : `tokens[counter]` does not point to memory that is reserved.

Comment: You have to allocate memory for your pointers i.e. `token = malloc(some_size);`

Comment: `strlen(tokens[i]) != 0` change to `i < counter`. because `char tokens[10][100];` is uninitialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate memory for each element of the `tokens` array.

Easy way is to declare it as

```
#define SOME_SIZE 100

char tokens[10][SOME_SIZE];
```

Otherwise, `tokens[0]`, `tokens[1]` etc point to some random location in memory. `strcpy`ing to that random location is causing your program to crash.

Comment: It doesn't seg fault now until I try to output it to standard output. It outputs a lot of crap until it eventually gives me a seg fault. I'm working on it again but thought I'd add this.

Comment: And I fixed that by changing the for loops from doing != NULL to strlen(text) != 0.